# Why is the higlighted equivalence true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, biology

I am not able to see why the equivalence highlighted is true? Is it possible to move the u from the right hand side of A on to the left hand side?

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

- $Au$ is a column vector wich components are the sum of the columns components that is $(Au)_i=\sum_{j=1}^N A_{ij}$
- $u\cdot Au$ is the sum of all $A_{ij}$ that is $\sum_{ij} A_{ij}$
- $u^2=u\cdot u=1+1+\dots+1=N$

Comment: why did you take u to be a column vector rather than row?

Comment: @chloeloughan usually when we write a vector as $\vec u$ we are referring to a column vector while $\vec u^T$ indicates a row vector. But it is not essential for the proof given here.

Comment: The matrix multiplication $Au$ is defined for a *column vector* $u$. And the dot product is $x\dot y=x^Ty$.